# Replace variables what represents jQuery selectors with those selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, reformatting

I have this code:

```
var A = $("#test1");
var B = $("#test2");
console.log(A.val());
console.log(B.val());
```

How to replace `A` & `B` with jQuery selectors to achieve `console.log($("#div2").val());` and remove `A` & `B` completely?

I mean, I need reformat/refractor file automatically. Not change code programmatically. I can use Python, PHP, or C# for example, but I don't know where start.

Comment: `#div1` and `#div2` supposed to be `<div>` tags. Note that `div` element doesn't have `value` property.

Comment: No ;) It doesn't matter. It can be `<input id="div1"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var A = $("#div1");
console.log(A[0].val());
```

or

```
var A = $("#div1");
console.log($(A).val());
```

Comment: I said I want to replace it in file, to remove A variable completely. Not make it programmatically

Comment: If I understood correctly you want in the actual files to string replace A. with $(''). yes?